# How to get a ruby class name and field name on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 u=User.find(:first)
 u.to_s
 => "#<User:0x9b017ac>"
```

how can i output `User` this class string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get the class name, try:

```
u.class.to_s
```

**Edit:**

As Sergey pointed out in his answer it is better to use

```
u.class.name
```

I believe that is because `to_s` could be overwritten and it could possibly return a different string that the one returned by `name`.

Answer (score 8):

The most "right" way from Ruby documentation is to use u.class.name
Updated: the answer - u.name.to_s that was selected as correct - not right, cause:

for example:

```
class A
  def self.to_s
    "BBB"
  end
end

ruby-1.8.7-p302 > a.class.to_s
 => "BBB" 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > a.class.name
 => "A"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `u.inspect` and see if any of that info fits your needs.